# C# with sql query result to variable

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm new in C#, so maybe i didn't wrotte it correctly.

In my `C#` form, i put `order nr.` into a form.
Then it check this in `sql`.

need to execute this query:

1. Get `OrderID` from `Order nr.`
2. Need to check if `Order ID` is in `[System_Opened_Orders]` = order is opened
3. If order is opened, then need to run in C# `Messagebox.Show("Order opened, try again later")`
4. If is not opened, load data from `order`

***SQL query:***

```
    Declare @OrderID uniqueidentifier
    SET @OrderID = (SELECT m.ID FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[orders] m
    WHERE m.OrderNumber= @sqlordernr)
```

```
if EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[System_Opened_Orders] 
        WHERE Record_ID=@OrderID )
            BEGIN
                  // Tell its opened, need try again later
            END

        ELSE
            BEGIN
                   // Order is not openend, can get custommer data
                   select ID, OrderNumber, CustommerName, CustommerCity
                   FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[orders] where OrderNumber = @sqlordernr
            END
```

***C# code:***

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=Agenda;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=xxxxxxxx");
            conn.Open();

            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(/*sql query*/, conn);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sqlordernr", odernr);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
            {
                if (reader.Read())
                {
                   // if order is opened then Messagebox.Show

                   // if is not opened 
                   // String OrderCustommerName = reader.GetString(3).TrimEnd();
                   // String OrderCustommerCity= reader.GetString(4).TrimEnd();
                   // lbOrderData.Text = OrderCustommerName + " " + OrderCustommerCity;
                }
            }
            conn.Close();
```

Comment: The answer is good but if you want you can try SQL [output parameters](http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/How-to-return-Output-parameter-from-Stored-Procedure-in-ASPNet-in-C-and-VBNet.aspx) as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return something from your if statement inside the stored procedure. You can simply return a single value

```
if EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[System_Opened_Orders] 
    WHERE Record_ID=@OrderID )
        BEGIN
            select 1 
        END
    ELSE
        BEGIN
           -- Order is not openend, get custommer data
           select ID, OrderNumber, CustommerName, CustommerCity
           FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[orders] where OrderNumber = @sqlordernr
        END
```

Now you can tell the difference between the two results looking at the property [FieldCount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.fieldcount(v=vs.110).aspx) of the DataReader

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    if (reader.FieldCount == 1)
        MessageBox.Show("Order open");
    else
    {
        while(reader.Read())
        {
           // String OrderCustommerName = reader.GetString(3).TrimEnd();
           // String OrderCustommerCity= reader.GetString(4).TrimEnd();
           // lbOrderData.Text = OrderCustommerName + " " + OrderCustommerCity;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to select anything if *"order is opened"*

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[System_Opened_Orders] WHERE Record_ID=@OrderID )
BEGIN
    -- Order is not openend, get custommer data
    select ID, OrderNumber, CustommerName, CustommerCity
    FROM [Agenda].[dbo].[orders] where OrderNumber = @sqlordernr
END
```

And then at code side; if there is no row at datareader, while.Read() will return **false**

```
using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
    while(reader.Read())
    {
       // String OrderCustommerName = reader.GetString(3).TrimEnd();
       // String OrderCustommerCity= reader.GetString(4).TrimEnd();
       // lbOrderData.Text = OrderCustommerName + " " + OrderCustommerCity;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, very simple, but in my case is better to use the `select 1`